# How can I clean some white leather shoes?

Tags: cleaning, shoes

I have a pair of white leather shoes, that are still in very good condition, but are quite dirty and thus look scruffy.

How can I clean them up to make them look nice again?

Comment: Please describe what you have tried already.

Comment: @holroy I haven't tried anything.

Comment: Then you should try searching for tips and tricks on the internet. This question as it stands, without any attempts to solve it, does not require any life hacks, but just a simple "how to wash leather shoes". That is a reason for closing the question as off-topic...

Answer (score 1):

Use a kitchen cleaner and a slightly damp soft cloth - I generally try Mr. Muscle first, a spray cleaner meant for worktops and the like, but usually finish up using a cream abrasive such as Cif to get off excessive mud and marks on my leather trainers. Wipe over with a different, damp cloth to get off any residue, allow to dry and finish off with a white shoe treatment such as Scuff Kote.